# Powers of 2 above and below input

Tags: c, function, loops, pointers

I have the programming reading in middle just fine however using the pointer with below and above is not giving the correct value to be found using middle.

Why is below (most likely above as well) negative when running in the for loop?
Am I calling using pointers in the correct way?

```
/*
 *
 *Function pwrTwo has one parameter "middle" it reads the inout from the user 
 *to find below and above
 *
 *the function is used to find the highest power of two below middle
 *and the lowest power of two above middle
 *
 *The function then returns the two values and they are printed in the
 * the main function displayed as below<middle<above
 *
 */

#include <stdio.h>

int pwrTwo(int m, int*above, int*below) {

  int i = 0;
  *above = 0;
  *below = 0;

  for (i = 2; *below < m; i += 1) {
    *below = pow(2, i);
    printf("%d,%d,%d\n", below, m, i); //my check to see if below middle and i are correct
  }

  for (i += 3; *above > m; i -= 1) {
    *above = pow(2, i);
    printf("%d,%d,%d\n", below, m, above); // checking again
  }

  return;
}

int main() {

  int middle = 1;
  int above = 0;
  int below = 0;

  while (middle > 0) {
    printf("Please input a value:");
    scanf("%d", &middle);
    pwrTwo(middle, &above, &below);
    printf("%d<%d<%d\n", below, middle, above);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to include  to use pow function
Since you are getting the values in the parameters, your return type should be void,
and you dont need to use pointers in this case, you want just one value for below, and one for above, so you just use a int..but... 
you can work with this:

```
void pwrTwo(int m, int*above,int*below){
double log2m = log2(m);
*below = pow(2,floor(log2m));
*above = pow(2,ceil(log2m));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `printf` with an `int*` instead of in an `int`. I am surprised your compiler did not give you warnings, since my compiler gives me warnings about this.

When you print a pointer as an `int`, you will get a negative number if the sign bit happens to be set for the address it stores.

Try changing

```
printf("%d,%d,%d\n",below,m,i)
```

to

```
printf("%d,%d,%d\n",*below,m,i)
```

as well as changing `printf("%d,%d,%d\n",below,m,above)` to `printf("%d,%d,%d\n",*below,m,*above)`.

Answer (score 0):

#3 is the main issue.

1) Missing `#include <math.h>`

2) Mis-matched return.  Change from

```
int pwrTwo(int m, int*above, int*below) {
  ...
  return;
}
```

to

```
void pwrTwo(int m, int*above, int*below) {
  ...
  // return;
}
```

3) Wrong types in `printf()`

```
// printf("%d,%d,%d\n", below, m, i);
printf("%d,%d,%d\n", *below, m, i);
...
// printf("%d,%d,%d\n", below, m, above);
printf("%d,%d,%d\n", *below, m, *above);
...
```

4) Good idea to check return value from `scanf()`

```
// scanf("%d", &middle);
if (scanf("%d", &middle) != 1) Handle_Error();
```

5) Code may simplify.  Watch out for range errors.

```
// some_int = pow(2, i);
some_int = 1 << i;
```